# AWS - DSN ODBC 64 bits - Simba Athena

Tags: odbc, 64-bit, amazon-athena, dsn, simba

I'm trying to config one connection DSN 64 Bits with an Simba Athena driver.

But when test i'm getting the follow error:

[image]

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved installing more advance version of simba 1.1

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/connect-with-odbc.html

I was using the version 1.0.5.